# Deleting Abbreviated Longitude value with 'e' in it

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning, geopandas, data-wrangling

I've got a dataset with 300k plus longitude and latitude coordinates

I'm trying reverse geocode to get each district in a column upon carrying this out I got an error message --->

'Must be a coordinate pair or Point'---> `ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point`

upon investigation, I realised some of my coordinates have been abbreviated using 'e' like this `-1e-05`

.... would anyone be able to help me remove all values in the Longitude column which has the `e` abbreviation, please????

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> num = float(1e-05)
>>> print(format(num,'f'))
0.000010
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you are into f-strings, `f'{num:f}'`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into float

```py
num = '-1e-9'
num = float(num)
```

If you are using `pandas` and your column is named `latitud`

```py
df['latitud'] = df['latitud'].apply(float)
```

If the values are of the form `'2.3, -3.8'`

```
df['latitud'] = df['latitud'].apply(lambda item: ','.join(map(lambda value: str(float(value)), item.split(','))))
```

Check out, if the column have other string that are not able to convert to float it will show an error.

Comment: Hi thank you but what I have done is I've made a 'geo' column of all latitude and longitude paired to be able to convert then when applying the suggestion you have mentioned to the 'Geo' column I get `Could not convert string to float: '51.513338,-0.133649'`